# What are the solutions for discrete integers b, d to $a^b \equiv c^d \pmod p$ where $p$ is a large prime number?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a way to efficiently discover or choose the integers $b$, $d$ for the congruence relationship below where $p$ is a large prime number? Is there a name for this relationship?

$$
a^{b} = c^{d} \pmod p
$$

Comment: I think what you are asking is the discrete logarithm problem, which is one of the foundations of the modern cryptography.

Comment: $b=d=p-1$ I suppose. Sometimes $(p-1)/2$.

Comment: You could start with b and d both p-1, and try  divisors of p-1 after that.

Comment: One further restriction -- a^b (mod p) and c^d (mod p) should be between 2 and (p-1)

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev -- I am wondering this myself, is there a way to show that this is the case? I can think of one way it is not, and that is when the ratio of log(c) to log(a) is a rational number -- then this is trivial to solve. What about when log(c) to log(a) is irrational?

Comment: so the easy solutions without doing much work are:
b = d = 0 (b = d = (p-1)  and (maybe? (p-1)/2)). 

I am interested in the other solutions though and what this problem might be called

Comment: I've got the feeling that it is equivalent to ask for an efficien,

Comment: I'sorry for the bad editing (see above)...I've got the feeling that it is equivalent to find efficiently the smallest primitive root mod p. If you name it g(p), it seems that Burgess (1962) proves that for every a>0, there exists a constant C(a) such that g(p)< C(a) p^(0.25+a) , which is not so bad an upper bound.

Comment: If $c=a^x$ you get something quite close to discrete logarithm.

Comment: Note the case $c=1$ is asking to find the order of $a$ modulo $p$ (if you aren't satisfied with the easy solutions), and if $p$ is a large prime it may be infeasible to factor $p-1$, so that approach is ruled out.

Comment: @Smaug: it's not enough to find a primitive root - you'd then need to express both $a$ and $c$ as powers of the primitive root, which is a special case of the original problem.

Comment: @GregMartin : yes, you're perfectly right, I apologize for  stupidly writing without thinking twice. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry - if I had to apologize every time I wrote something imperfect on this site, I'd never have time for anything else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, this is essentially the discrete logarithm problem.
Since $a^{p-1}=c^{p-1}=1$, $b,d$ are naturally thought of best as modulo $p-1$.
Now for any solution, we can factor $d= d'\cdot gcd(d,p-1)$. Then $d'$ is invertible modulo $p-1$, so we can find some $e$ for which $d'e = 1$ modulo $p-1$. Setting $c' = c^{gcd(d,p-1)}$, taking the $e$-th power of the original equation gives you
$$
a^{be} = c'
$$
mod $p$. Now finding $be$ here is exactly the discrete logarithm problem.

You can get your original equation back by powering with $d'$ again (since $d'e=1$ mod $p-1$),
so this describes all solutions. More precisely, let $k$ run through divisors $k | p-1$, let $x$ run through all solutions of the discrete logarithm problem $a^x = c^k$, and $d'$ through all things invertible mod $p-1$, then $(c,d) = (d'x, d'k)$ describes all solutions mod $p-1$.

As was also mentioned in the comments, this discrete logarithm problem is believed to be not efficiently solvable, and a lot of modern cryptography depends on that.